# Dynamically change the frequency of interval Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

In constructor I have a function:

```
const inter= interval(1000);
inter.subscribe(val => {this.function()});
```

My function is calling every 1 sec by default. I have an input field where user can pass new time interval. How can I change frequency of calling `this.function()` to frequency got from input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Subject`s:

```
private intervalSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1000); // default 1000ms interval

private interval$ = this.intervalSubject.pipe(
  switchMap(duration => interval(duration))
);

ngOnInit() {
  this.interval$.subscribe(() => this.func());
}

handleInputChanged(newInputNumber: number) {
  this.intervalSubject.next(newInputNumber); // make sure the input is of type number, not string
}

func() {
  console.log('called!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const frequency$ = new Subject();
const inter = frequency$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(freq => interval(freq)),
  )
```

Eventually, you can use `BehaviorSubject()` with a default value. To set new frequency you can use `frequency$.next(1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference for you:

https://angular-cvrsan.stackblitz.io

`switchMap` to cancel your previous interval source